# How do I remove/disable the scrollTop function with JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to write a script that has several variable and functions. The script is for a navbar and it should do the following:

1. On scroll:change bg from transparent to solid, and change logo img.
2. On small screens:change bg from transparent to solid, and change logo img.

The problem is that I can get it to work with one or the other but not both.
What happens is the resize works on small screen UNTIL you scroll down and back up. When it hits the top it the background goes back to transparent.

Is there a way to remove the scrollTop function on smaller screens? I feel like removing/disabling this function would fix the problem.

*** Is there a way to do something like this? ***

```
if (width < 786) {
  //REMOVE scrollTop;//?
}
```

I'm just trying to figure out how to remove the scrollTop function if the screen is small.

I have tried placing the functions in separate scripts, and also using @media css, which comes the closest to working so far, but the "green" logo disappears when scroll hits top.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     $(window).resize(function() {
       var height = $('.first-container').height();
       var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       var width = $(window).width();
    
       if (scrollTop >= 0 || width < 768) {
         $('.nav-container').addClass('solid-nav') && 
         $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','images/new-green-sm.png');
       } else {
         $('.nav-container').removeClass('solid-nav') &&
         $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','images/new-white-sm.png');
       }    
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: I guess the mistake might happen because you put `&&` after the `addClass` statement? Because the rest of the code seems to be working as intended.

Comment: Or your mobile width is not actually smaller than 768 pixels. (try loggint the width)

Comment: Also I would suggest you to move the function in its own function and call it from scroll and resize, because it ist not good to put the resize listener inside the scroll listener

Comment: You might want to consider using `hasClass()` instead of using the hacky `&&`. It's clearer and less likely to result in unexpected errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am very new to js. What does hasClass() do? Can you give me an example to look at?

Comment: If it "feel[s] like removing/disabling this function would fix the problem", question that feeling: don't mess with how JS is _supposed_ to work, and try to fix the problem rather than patching over the symptom. If your styling is going wrong on small screen sizes, use media query CSS to make sure there is nothing to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this when you want to test the width to remove the function.

```
if (width < 768) {
  scrollTop = function(){};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just always set `scrollTop` to 0 if `width < 768` instead of calling the `scrollTop` method :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     $(window).resize(function() {
       var height = $('.first-container').height();
       var width = $(window).width();
       // Set scrollTop always to 0 if width < 768
       var scrollTop = (width < 768) ? 0 : $(window).scrollTop();
    
       if (scrollTop >= 0 || width < 768) {
         $('.nav-container').addClass('solid-nav') && 
         $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','images/new-green-sm.png');
       } else {
         $('.nav-container').removeClass('solid-nav') &&
         $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','images/new-white-sm.png');
       }    
     });
   });
 });
```

This way if will never execute the second part of your if-statement if `width < 768`, no matter what the value of `scrollTop` is.